# How to evaluate the following derivative of integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

I have an integral 
$$I(a)=\int_0^{a}\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\sqrt{\int_{r}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\frac{f(x)}{x^2}}},$$ where $f(x)>0$ is some real valued function. I need to find the following:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}I(a)}{\mathrm{d}a}~.$$
I did the following: first take derivative with respect to the outer $a$, and second take derivative with respect to the inner $a$. That is
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}I(a)}{\mathrm{d}a}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\int_{a}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\frac{f(x)}{x^2}}}-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{a}\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\left(\int_{r}^{a}\mathrm{d}x\frac{f(x)}{x^2}\right)^{3/2}}\frac{f(a)}{a^2}.$$

However, this certainly does not look right, as the first term diverges. Can any one let me know where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to analyse the square root term first.

Now, considering that you have a generic $f(x)$, we cannot say that much. We may try some tricky substitution to make the integral to look prettier but who knows.

Let's say

$$\frac{1}{x^2} = t^2 ~~~~~~~ \text{d}x = -\frac{1}{t^2}\ \text{d}t = -x^2\ \text{d}t$$

hence you get

$$\int_a^r \frac{f(x)}{x^2}\ \text{d}x = \int_{1/a^2}^{1/r^2}\ f\left(\frac{1}{t}\right) t^2 \ \frac{-\text{d}t}{t^2} = \int_{1/r^2}^{1/a^2} f\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\text{d}t$$

Knowing nothing about $f$ we assume it does converge in that range, and we may write the solution as $F(1/t)$ according to the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$$F(a^2) - F(r^2)$$

Hence now it's about the rest:

$$I(a) = \int_0^a\ \frac{\text{d}r}{\sqrt{F(a^2) - F(r^2)}}$$

Now the derivative.

$$\frac{\text{d}I(a)}{\text{d}a} = \int_0^a\ \text{d}r\ \left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}a} \frac{1}{\sqrt{F(a^2) - F(r^2)}}\right) = \int_0^a\ \text{d}r\ \left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(F(a^2) - F(r^2)\right)^{-3/2}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}a}F(a^2)\right)$$

Namely, arranging things a bit

$$\frac{\text{d}I(a)}{\text{d}a} = -\frac{1}{2}\int_0^a\ \text{d}r\ \frac{1}{(F(a^2) - F(r^2))^{3/2}} \left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}a}F(a^2)\right)$$

Comment: Your step on taking $dI(a)/da$: why did you integrate only the inner integrand. The integration limit is by itself a function of $a$.

Comment: @titanium It's the same. Let's pretend you have to compute the derivative of $I(a)$ where $I(a)$ is, let's say, this simple integral:

$$I(a) = \int_0^a\ a\ \text{d}a$$

Now you can compute the integral, which is trivial and it gives you $$\frac{a^2}{2}$$ hence

$$\frac{d\ I(a)}{d\ a} = a$$

or you can bring the derivative inside before to compute the integral, getting:

$$\int_0^a\ \frac{d}{d\ a}\ a\ \text{d}a = \int_0^a\ 1 \ \text{d}a$$

Now you do the integral and you get

$$a$$

See? It's the same thing.

Comment: I don't agree with that. Your integral is $I(a)=\int_0^a x\mathrm{d}x$, which upon differentiating with respect to $a$ should give $a$. Your answer is correct in that case, but you did not use the right approach. Now take $$I(a)=\int_0^a(x-a)dx.$$ In this case, proper way of finding derivative is $$\frac{dI}{da}=(a-a)+\int_0^a\frac{d}{da}(x-a)dx=-a$$, which is what you expect with direct integration and then differentiation.

Comment: No. If you want to deal with your example, we have again two cases:

$$\frac{dI}{da} = \int_0^a \frac{d}{da}\ (x-a) \ \text{d}a = \int_0^a\ -1\ \text{d}a = -a$$

And

$$\frac{dI}{da} = \frac{d}{da} \int_0^a\ (x-a)\ \text{d}a = \frac{d}{da} \left(\frac{a^2}{2} - a\right) = \frac{d}{da}\left(-\frac{a^2}{2}\right) = -a$$

It's the same.